# Unable to load libsctp.so for non root user

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a Linux application that uses the libsctp.so library. When I run it as root, it runs fine.

But when I run it as an ordinary user, it gives the following error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libsctp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But, when I do ldd as ordinary user, it is able to see the library:

> [sanjeev@devtest6 src]$ ldd myapp
>
> ```
>   ...
>    ...
>   libsctp.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libsctp.so.1 (0x00d17000)
> ```
>
> [sanjeev@devtest6 src]$ ls -lL /usr/local/lib/libsctp.so.1
>
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27430 2009-06-29 11:26 /usr/local/lib/libsctp.so.1
>
> [sanjeev@devtest6 src]$

What could be wrong? How is the ldd is able to find libsctp.so, but when actually running the app, it is not able to find the same library?

EDIT: Just observed that this problem appears only if setuid bit is set for myapp.

Comment: run strace on your app, see what happens. Also is libsctp.so.1 a symlink to something else ?

Comment: strace shows the below output: open("/usr/lib/libsctp.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory).
Also, I found out something else: this app has setuid bit set. i.e. ls -l myapp: -rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 2260821 2010-04-01 17:55 myapp. If I remove that setuid bit, then it is able to find the library. Only if setuid bit is set, it is not able to find the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem. I added a new file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d with the followng name:

> **libsctp.so.1.conf**

The contents of libsctp.so.1.conf is as follows:

> **/usr/local/lib/**

And then ran

> /sbin/ldconfig

, after which my app ran successfully.

Explanation: Since the setuid bit was set, the program is executed as root, for whom LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not available. Hence it is not able to find libsctp.so. I was not aware of this because when I login as root, .bashrc gets executed and LD_LIBRARY_PATH becomes available.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same exception on Ubuntu 18.04, after executing the following code:

```
SctpServerChannel s = SctpServerChannel.open();
```

The issue was solved after running:

```
sudo apt-get install libsctp1
```

Comment: confirm ... 20.04

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of environment setting difference.

You may need to add `/usr/local/lib/` to LIBRARY_PATH or kind of.

Comment: I already have /usr/local/lib in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. AFAIK, ldd is also dependent on the same environment setting.

Comment: @sankoz, I see, if me, I will just do `env | grep "/usr/local/lib/"` on root and will try to copy all matched lines to non-root user too. It could even  need to add to PATH, which is not so normal though.

Comment: @S.Mark, the only env variable is PATH, which I have copied.

Answer (score 0):

You can recieve that error if a shared library that `libsctp.so` itself depends on is not found (yes, it is a little confusing).  Try `ldd` on the library itself:

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/libsctp.so.1
```

Comment: ldd on the library is working fine.
[sanjeev@devtest6 src]$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libsctp.so.1
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x0034a000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x008ec000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0070b000)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before switching to root user or after that? When you run `ldd` as root does it still find all dependent libraries?

```
dmitry@debian:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

dmitry@debian:~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
dmitry@debian:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib
dmitry@debian:~$ su
Password:
debian:/home/dmitry# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

debian:/home/dmitry#
```

Comment: I have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in both cases (root and non-root). ldd as root and non-root yield the same result.